# Не отправляется сообщение в телеграм

Tags: python, telebot, бот

```
import telebot

ID="1632649927"
token="TOKEN"

bot=telebot.TeleBot(token)

bot.send_message(ID,"Hello")
```

Comment: А Вы откуда отправляете сообщение?

Comment: Возможно так: bot.send_message(ID, text='Hello')

Comment: В пайчарме запускаю скрипт. C text все равно не работает

Comment: Указивать свой телеграм айди просто правильно ? Или нужен айди бота ?

Comment: Какая-то ошибка может?

Comment: @Frankinshtein ID - чата или юзера, но с юзером надо чтобы до этого общение было

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio
async def something():
    await bot.send_message(ID,"Hello")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
asyncio.run(something())
```

Comment: Библиотека telebot не асинхронная